# how to grep the records having exact length specified

Tags: linux

We have a file having 100000 records in unix. We want to filter the records having record length=1000

If we have record length greater than 1000 then we want to ignore those record in the final fine.. I tried below command but not working exactly

```
grep -x '.\{1000,1000\}' File
```

Comment: Can you describe which version of `grep` you are using, and in what way it doesn't behave as expected?

Comment: Are those "records" terminated by a new line character, or how else?

Comment: @RudiC.. I do have some millions of records. As per fixed with file i should have length = 1000. Due to some special characters or something it has more length. When i used awk print length i have got the length as 1002 ,1003 for few records. So i am trying to create a file with only records having length=1000. Is there any way i can create a file much faster

Comment: @Paul_Pedant are you sure about the first part of your comment? The man page of (at least GNU `grep`) says that the `-x` option enforces matches of the whole line, "like parenthesizing the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $".

Comment: Question says we have "100000 records", comment says "some millions of records". You might run: time wc File; so we can see how long wc takes to read it, and how much data there really is. Do you know the longest line?

Comment: You might take an interest in what those extra 2 or 3 chars are. They might easily be because you have UTF-8 wide characters, so you have 1000 characters but 1003 bytes, for example. Could also be the magic prefix (Byte Order Mark), and if you concatenated several files these can occur in the text body.

Answer (score 2):

you can use awk to print only the records having 1000 characters

```
awk 'length==1000' File
```

which is exactly equivalent to the below

```
awk 'length($0)==1000{print $0}' File
```

by default, when the condition is met, awk will print the line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But command is taking more time to create a file. Is there any other way i can create faster

Answer (score 1):

maybe Awk by doing.

```
awk 'length($0) == 1000' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But command is taking more time to create a file. Is there any other way i can create faster

Comment: might be a buffering issue. see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

Answer (score 0):

A solution in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

f = open('filename.log', 'r')
for line in f:
    if len(line) > 1000:
        continue
    else:
        # do the stuff
f.close()
```